# Error when activating org-mode unless speedbar loaded first

Tags: org-mode, use-package, side-bar

Whenever I open an org file before the speedbar package is loaded, org-mode produces the following error:

```
Symbol’s function definition is void: speedbar-add-supported-extension
```

The error above is resolved if I `(require 'speedbar)` in my init file but, as a learning experience, I was wondering if there's a way of deferring loading of speedbar until such a time when org-mode is actually initialized for the first time.

I've tried:

- specifying the `:after` prop to `use-package`:

  ```
  (use-package org
    :hook (org-mode . init/mode/org)
    :after speedbar
    :config
    (init/org-mode))
  ```
- setting up an advice

  ```
  (advice-add 'org-mode :before #'init/org-mode))
  ```

Nothing worked so far. Is there a way of accomplishing this?

**EDIT**

Using Emacs 26.3 and org-mode 9.1.9 .

Comment: Is it autoloadable?

Comment: You didn't say what version of Emacs and org-mode you're using. I took a look in the org-mode source code, and `speedbar-add-supported-extension` is only called after speedbar is loaded. Perhaps this is a bug that was fixed, and you're using an older version of org-mode?

Comment: Thanks @db48, I've updated my post.

Comment: Curious; my version is 9.1.2 and it doesn't have the problem.